# Call operator<< for a base class from within operator<< for a derived class, when they are not class members in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, derived-class

I have a base `b` and a derived `d` classes.
Within `operator<<` for `d` (which is not a class member) I want to call `operator<<` for `b`, plus other actions.
I used `static_cast` for that.

Is there any other way to achieve the same?
What are pros and cons of the alternatives?

```
class b {
};

class d : public b {
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const b& bi) {
    os << "base";
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const d& di) {
    // call operator for the base class...;
    os << static_cast<b>(di) << endl;
    os << " ... and derived";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<const b&>(di)` will prevent making an unnecessary copy of your `b`.

Comment: Why is the operator-overloading relevant here? Isn't it the same situation non-member functions `foo(b)` and `foo(d)`?

Answer (score 4):

This would be better handled by defining only 1 `operator<<` for just `b`, and then add a `virtual` method in `b` for that `operator<<` to call, and then have `d` override that method, eg:

```
class b {
public:
    virtual void printTo(ostream& os) const;
};

class d : public b {
public:
    void printTo(ostream& os) const override;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const b& bi) {
    bi.printTo(os);
    return os;
}

void b::printTo(ostream& os) const {
    os << "base";
}

void d::printTo(ostream& os) const {
    b::printTo(os);
    os << endl << " ... and derived";
}
```

Comment: I know that is one option. Do you see a way of handling this via class methods, but sticking to operator<<?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio "*I know that is one option*" - well, then you should have mentioned it in your question.  You asked for alternatives, I gave you one.

Comment: This changed the interface of the class hierarchy though. Previously it was not possible to use runtime polymorphism, now it is.

Comment: @Henk the classes were already polymorphic to begin with, so better to utilize a polymorphic solution. No need to define 2 `operator<<`s when 1 will suffice, since a `d` object can bind to a `const b&` reference.

Comment: Is there any aspect on which the method you suggested, or that in the OP, are preferable?
What do you mean by "better handled"?